# Returning multiple values independently from __str__ for ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the models.py as:

```
class FoodCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    content = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null = True,blank=True)
    preparation = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.category, self.content, self.preparation, self.time)
```

Now I have filled some values for the FoodCategory from django admin site.And I need to display these values as drop down fields ie a dropdown field for category, another drop down field for content and similiarly for preparation and time.

My forms.py is as follows:

```
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    time = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    preparation = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    content = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = FoodItems
        fields = ('name','time', 'category', 'content', 'preparation', 'comment',)
```

But now all the dropdown fields are displaying as:

[image: I need to seperate Starter-Soup, Veg, American, Breakfast to category,content, preparation, time respectively]

I need to seperate Starter-Soup, Veg, American, Breakfast to category,content, preparation, time respectively

So I think the problem is with the return value of `__str__`. How can I return them individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this by creating custom modelchoice fields:

```
class CategoryModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.category

class TimeModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.time

class PreparationModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.preparation

class ContentModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.content
```

forms.py :

```
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = CategoryModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    time = TimeModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    preparation = PreparationModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    content = ContentModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = FoodItems
        fields = ('name','time', 'category', 'content', 'preparation', 'comment',)
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! This works.. But how is the method `label_from_instance(self, obj)` being called? I am relatively new to python and django

Comment: The __str__ (__unicode__ on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it. For more info please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/

Comment: There is an another option availabe for specify the field to use as the value of the choices in the field’s widget 'to_field_name'

Comment: I have encountered a problem. Now when I save the choice field values it is saved as a whole eg: Starter_soup Veg American Breakfast for each of the columns category, content, preparation, time